# deleting/creating apache error log > log not updating

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

The error log file was quite big so I deleted it and created it again.. But now the error log is not logging/updating on errors?

Have tried to respart apache, but still the same..

I remember I experienced this a while ago.. Can't remember how it was fixed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apache keeps its log files open so deleting a log file stops apache from logging to it, since the old file descriptor now points to a deleted inode.

You should rotate/delete/truncate the log file, re-create it *with the correct ownership and permissions*, and then issue an `apachectl graceful` to reload.

Alternatively, apache can log errors to syslog; this does not suffer from the same limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you may want to use [rotatelogs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/rotatelogs.html) to constrain size/age of your httpd logs.